# I want a basic syntax to create a time dimension table in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I want to create a time dimension table so that I can have data inserted for example for every minute of a certain day or every hour of a certain day. I have already made a date dimension table so I hope I can eventually reference my time dimesnion table with my date dimension table to for example select data for a specific time on a specific day throughout the year.

Thanks

Comment: What do you actally need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just have column with a **timestamp** datatype in your table

whenever you insert data into the table have a function **now()** to inset data inplace of timstamp column

when you want to select the data in a particular timeframe and in particular data use **between**

use other [date functions](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_dates.asp) to get the data you desire

Answer (score 0):

Not getting your question fully but hope cron job will help you.